# Idiomatic way to recurse through collections in Clojure

Tags: data-structures, recursion, clojure

I'm trying to understand what is the idiomatic way in Clojure to recurse through a tree or a list represented by a Clojure list (or another collection type).

I could write the following to count the elements in a flat collection (ignore the fact that it's not tail-recursive):

```
(defn length
  ([xs]
     (if (nil? (seq xs))
       0
       (+ 1 (length (rest xs))))))
```

Now in Scheme or CL all the examples only ever do this over lists, so the idiomatic base case test in those languages would be `(nil? xs)`. In Clojure we'd like this function to work on all collection types, so is the idiomatic test `(nil? (seq xs))`, or maybe `(empty? xs)`, or something completely different?

The other case I'd like to consider is tree traversal, i.e. traversing through a list or vector that represents a tree, e.g. `[1 2 [3 4]`.

For example, counting the nodes in a tree:

```
(defn node-count [tree]
  (cond (not (coll? tree)) 1
        (nil? (seq tree)) 0
        :else (+ (node-count (first tree)) (node-count (rest tree)))))
```

Here we use `(not (coll? tree))` to check for atoms, whereas in Scheme/CL we'd use `atom?`. We also use `(nil? (seq tree))` to check for an empty collection. And finally we use `first` and `rest` to destructure the current tree to the left branch and the rest of the tree.

So to summarise, are the following forms idiomatic in Clojure:

- `(nil? (seq xs))` to test for the empty collection
- `(first xs)` and `(rest xs)` to dig into the collection
- `(not (coll? xs))` to check for atoms

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The idiomatic test for a non-empty seqable is `(seq coll)`:

```
(if (seq coll)
  ...
  )
```

The `nil?` is unnecessary, since a non-`nil` return value from `seq` is guaranteed to be a seq and thus neither `nil` nor `false` and therefore truthy.

If you want to deal with the `nil` case first, you can change the `if` to `if-not` or `seq` to `empty?`; the latter is implemented as a composition of `seq` with `not` (which is why it is not idiomatic to write `(not (empty? xs))`, cf. the docstring of `empty?`).

As for `first` / `rest` -- it's useful to remember about the strict variant of `rest`, `next`, the use of which is more idiomatic than wrapping `rest` in a `seq`.

Finally, `coll?` checks if its argument is a Clojure persistent collection (an instance of `clojure.lang.IPersistentCollection`). Whether this is an appropriate check for "non-atoms" depends on whether the code needs to handle Java data structures as non-atoms (via interop): e.g. `(coll? (java.util.HashSet.))` is `false`, as is `(coll? (into-array []))`, but you can call `seq` on both. There is a function called `seqable?` in [`core.incubator`](https://github.com/clojure/core.incubator) in the new modular contrib which promises to determine whether `(seq x)` would succeed for a given `x`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. About `rest`/`next`, so you're saying I should use `(length (next xs))` in the recursive call, because I'm going to call `seq` on the collection anyway? As for `coll?`, at this point I'm only interested in the native Clojure collection types, so `coll?` should do me just fine.

Comment: You're welcome. I mostly meant calling `seq` on the return value of `rest` directly (e.g. `(if-let [new-xs (seq (rest xs))] ...)`), where the idiom is definitely `(next xs)`, and `recur`ing with `rest`, which only makes sense if you might actually not call `seq` on the return value in the next iteration. In the case of your `length` function, I'd probably still use `next` to make it as clear as possible that the function is strict, but I'd say it doesn't make that much difference.

Answer (score 9):

I personally like the following approach to recurse through a collection:

```
(defn length
  "Calculate the length of a collection or sequence"
  ([coll]
     (if-let [[x & xs] (seq coll)]
       (+ 1 (length xs))
       0)))
```

Features:

- (seq coll) is idiomatic for testing whether a collection is empty (as per Michal's great answer)
- [if-let](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/if-let) with (seq coll) automatically handles both the nil and empty collection case
- You can use destructuring to name the first and next elements as you like for use in your function body

Note that in general it is better to write recursive functions using [recur](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/recur) if possible, so that you get the benefits of tail recursion and don't risk blowing up the stack. So with this in mind, I'd actually probably write this specific function as follows:

```
(defn length
  "Calculate the length of a collection or sequence"
  ([coll]
    (length coll 0))
  ([coll accumulator]
    (if-let [[x & xs] (seq coll)]
      (recur xs (inc accumulator))
      accumulator)))

(length (range 1000000))
=> 1000000
```

Comment: Nice! I wanted to concentrate on the collection recursion idiom without getting into tail calls, so I intentionally didn't use `recur`.

Comment: @mikera Does this work for lazy infinite sequences? (Say use map as an example instead of length for obvious reasons). My understanding is that vectors aren't lazy and so `(if-let [[x & xs] (seq coll)]` would explode, right?  (What's the workaround if so)?

Comment: The technique works OK for lazy infinite sequences, but only as long as you don't hold on to the head. If you keep a reference to the start of the sequence, the garbage collector won't be able to remove anything and you will run out of memory sooner or later.